# Redirect stderr output of c module to custom python writer

Tags: python

I would like to capture the stderr output of my program and apply some custom pre-processing before displaying it on the terminal.

The stderr is written by some C/C++ module that I do not control.

```
with redirect_stderr():
  # foo() execute `std::cerr << "some log" << std::endl`
  some_module.foo()
  # I would like to redirect the `std::cerr` string to MyCustomLogger.write
```

My current code redirect stderr to some temporary file, that I can read afterwards.

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def redirect_stderr():
  """Context manager which redirect all stderr output to."""
  # Original stderr file descriptor id
  stderr_fd = sys.stderr.fileno()
  # Duplcate original file descriptor to be able to restore it
  dup_stderr_fd = os.dup(stderr_fd)

  # Create new file descriptor
  tfile = tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode='w+b')

  def _redirect_stream(to_fd):
    # Flush and close original file descriptor
    sys.stderr.close()
    # Use the tempfile instead of stderr
    os.dup2(to_fd, stderr_fd)
    # Tell Python to use the new file to write to stderr
    sys.stderr = os.fdopen(stderr_fd, 'w')

  try:
    # Replace stderr by the new temp file
    _redirect_stream(tfile.fileno())
    yield
  finally:
    # Replace the new temp file by the original stderr
    _redirect_stream(dup_stderr_fd)

  tfile.flush()
  tfile.seek(0, io.SEEK_SET)
  print(tfile.read())
```

Is it possible to process the output string as soon it is generated (without having to wait the end of the context manager) ?

It may be possible with a thread which regularly look at the `tfile` every x sec, but I'm wondering if there is a better solution ?

Comment: why not just pipe the output through a python filter on the command-line?  Is there any stdout?

Comment: @cdarke The module that print to stderr is part of my python program (ex: some processing using C backend). I would like to redirect the output as it doesn't work well with other library that I'm using (tqdm).
Basically I would like to do this: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#redirecting-writing, but with modules writing from the C/C++ code.

Comment: So to be clear, you have a C module which writes to `stderr` but you want to capture that - sounds like a poor design in the backend in that case.

Comment: Maybe, but I don't really have any control over which library I can use so I'm trying to do with what I have.

Comment: I'm in the same boat and unable to fix this. A library that I'm using [prints directly to stderr](https://github.com/Distrotech/reportlab/search?q=colinear%21) and I want to get rid of this output entirely in my python program. Did you figure out a solution?